# ruby - shoes - edit_line function call

Tags: ruby, shoes

I have this code:

```
Shoes.app do

  data = [1,2,3,4] # could be also more

  data.each { |i|
    edit_line ("foo"){ puts i}
  }

end
```

when the value (foo) change in the edit_line field, I see in the terminal 1,2,3 or 4. But I need the value (.txt) from each edit_line field. How can I reference to it?
The problem is that data is dynamic and can have n entries.

In php there is something like $$var is there something in ruby? maybe this could help.

Comment: Pesto's answer works, so why don't you accept this answer so that this question can be closed ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see the data when an edit_line changes, you can make use of the `change` method and the `text` method:

```
Shoes.app do

  data = [1,2,3,4] # could be also more

  data.each do |i|
    edit_line('foo').change do |e| { puts "#Edit Line #{i} Changed: #{e.text}" }
  end
end
```

Since the default block to the `edit_line` method does the same thing, you can simplify this to:

```
Shoes.app do

  data = [1,2,3,4] # could be also more

  data.each do |i|
    edit_line 'foo' do |e| { puts "#Edit Line #{i} Changed: #{e.text}" }
  end
end
```

Also, note that using `do`/`end` instead of `{}` for multi-line blocks is the preferred style.

Answer (score 0):

A friend pointed me to this:

```
data.each_index { |i| data[i] = edit_line() { data[i].text } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need both the index and data stored there, you want `#each_with_index`.  I've never used Shoes so I can't help with that part, but `#each_with_index` works like so:

```
data = ["cat", "bat", "rat"]
data.each_with_index {|i, d| print "#{i} => #{d} "}
```

This will print:
0 => cat
1 => bat
2 => rat